# retrieve jtextfield data to work with clicked checkbox

Tags: java, swing

Grocery_shop class

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

/**
   Grocery shop class

*/

public class Grocery_shop extends JFrame
{

   private quantitypanel qty; // A panel for quantity
   private Grocery_items items;       // A panel for routine charge checkboxes
   private JPanel buttonPanel; // A panel for the buttons
   private JButton calcButton;         // Calculates everything
   private JButton exitButton;         // Exits the application



   /**
      Constructor
   */

   public Grocery_shop()
   {
      // Display a title.
      setTitle("Victor's Grocery Shop");

      // Specify what happens when the close button is clicked.
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


 // Create a NonRoutinePanel object.
      qty = new quantitypanel();
    //  qty.setBackground(Color.white);

      // Create a RoutinePanel object.
      items = new Grocery_items( qty );



      // Build the panel that contains the buttons.
      buildButtonPanel();

      // Add the panels to the content pane.
      add(items, BorderLayout.WEST);
      add(qty, BorderLayout.EAST);
      add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

      // Pack and display the window.
      pack();
      setVisible(true);
   }

   /**
      The buildButtonPanel method creates a panel containing
      buttons.
   */

   private void buildButtonPanel()
   {
      // Create a button to calculate the charges.
      calcButton = new JButton("Add Charges");

      // Add an action listener to the button.
      calcButton.addActionListener(new CalcButtonListener());

      // Create a button to exit the application.
      exitButton = new JButton("Exit");

      // Add an action listener to the button.
      exitButton.addActionListener(new ExitButtonListener());

      // Put the buttons in their own panel.
      buttonPanel = new JPanel();
      buttonPanel.add(calcButton);
      buttonPanel.add(exitButton);
   }

   /**
      CalcButtonListener is an action listener class for the
      calcButton component.
   */

   private class CalcButtonListener implements ActionListener
   {
      /**
         actionPerformed method
         @param e An ActionEvent object.
      */

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
         double totalCharges; // Total charges

         // Create a DecimalFormat object to format output.
         DecimalFormat dollar = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");

         // Calculate the total charges
         totalCharges = items.getCharges(); 
                 //+ nonRoutine.getCharges();

         // Display the message.
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total Charges: $" + 
                                             dollar.format(totalCharges));
      }
   } // End of inner class

   /**
      ExitButtonListener is an action listener class for the
      exitButton component.
   */

   private class ExitButtonListener implements ActionListener
   {
      /**
         actionPerformed method
         @param e An ActionEvent object.
      */

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
         System.exit(0);
      }
   } // End of inner class

   /**
      The main method creates an instance of the JoesAutomotive
      class, causing it to display its window.
   */

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Grocery_shop grocery = new Grocery_shop();
   }
}
```

Grocery_item class

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

/**
   Grocery shop class

*/

public class Grocery_shop extends JFrame
{

   private quantitypanel qty; // A panel for quantity
   private Grocery_items items;       // A panel for routine charge checkboxes
   private JPanel buttonPanel; // A panel for the buttons
   private JButton calcButton;         // Calculates everything
   private JButton exitButton;         // Exits the application



   /**
      Constructor
   */

   public Grocery_shop()
   {
      // Display a title.
      setTitle("Victor's Grocery Shop");

      // Specify what happens when the close button is clicked.
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


 // Create a NonRoutinePanel object.
      qty = new quantitypanel();
    //  qty.setBackground(Color.white);

      // Create a RoutinePanel object.
      items = new Grocery_items( qty );



      // Build the panel that contains the buttons.
      buildButtonPanel();

      // Add the panels to the content pane.
      add(items, BorderLayout.WEST);
      add(qty, BorderLayout.EAST);
      add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

      // Pack and display the window.
      pack();
      setVisible(true);
   }

   /**
      The buildButtonPanel method creates a panel containing
      buttons.
   */

   private void buildButtonPanel()
   {
      // Create a button to calculate the charges.
      calcButton = new JButton("Add Charges");

      // Add an action listener to the button.
      calcButton.addActionListener(new CalcButtonListener());

      // Create a button to exit the application.
      exitButton = new JButton("Exit");

      // Add an action listener to the button.
      exitButton.addActionListener(new ExitButtonListener());

      // Put the buttons in their own panel.
      buttonPanel = new JPanel();
      buttonPanel.add(calcButton);
      buttonPanel.add(exitButton);
   }

   /**
      CalcButtonListener is an action listener class for the
      calcButton component.
   */

   private class CalcButtonListener implements ActionListener
   {
      /**
         actionPerformed method
         @param e An ActionEvent object.
      */

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
         double totalCharges; // Total charges

         // Create a DecimalFormat object to format output.
         DecimalFormat dollar = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");

         // Calculate the total charges
         totalCharges = items.getCharges(); 
                 //+ nonRoutine.getCharges();

         // Display the message.
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total Charges: $" + 
                                             dollar.format(totalCharges));
      }
   } // End of inner class

   /**
      ExitButtonListener is an action listener class for the
      exitButton component.
   */

   private class ExitButtonListener implements ActionListener
   {
      /**
         actionPerformed method
         @param e An ActionEvent object.
      */

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
         System.exit(0);
      }
   } // End of inner class

   /**
      The main method creates an instance of the JoesAutomotive
      class, causing it to display its window.
   */

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Grocery_shop grocery = new Grocery_shop();
   }
}
```

quantitypanel class

```
//import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
//import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
//import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class quantitypanel extends JPanel {
     private JTextField baked_beans_JT;     // JTextField box for baked_beans
       private JTextField Cornflakes_JT;       // JTextField box for cornflakes
       private JTextField Sugar_JT; // JTextField box for sugar box
       private JTextField Tea_Bags_JT;    // JTextField box for tea bag
       private JTextField Instant_Coffee_JT;    // JTextField box for Instant_Coffee_Box
       private JTextField Bread_JT;       // JTextField box for bread box
       private JTextField Sausage_JT;  // JTextField box for sausage box
       private JTextField egg_JT;  // JTextField box for egg box
       private JTextField milk_JT;  // JTextField box for milk
       private JTextField potatoes_JT;  // JTextField box for potatoes


       public quantitypanel()
       {

           //create JTextField.
           baked_beans_JT = new JTextField(5);
           Cornflakes_JT = new JTextField(5);
           Sugar_JT = new JTextField(5);
           Tea_Bags_JT = new JTextField(5);
           Instant_Coffee_JT = new JTextField(5);
           Bread_JT = new JTextField(5);
           Sausage_JT = new JTextField(5);
           egg_JT = new JTextField(5);
           milk_JT = new JTextField(5);
           potatoes_JT = new JTextField(5);


           //initialize text field to 0
           baked_beans_JT.setText("0");
           Cornflakes_JT.setText("0");
           Sugar_JT.setText("0");
           Tea_Bags_JT.setText("0");
           Instant_Coffee_JT.setText("0");
           Bread_JT.setText("0");
           Sausage_JT.setText("0");
           egg_JT.setText("0");
           milk_JT.setText("0");
           potatoes_JT.setText("0");

         public double getBeanqty()
         {

             return Double.parseDouble(baked_beans_JT.getText());
         }


           //set Layout manager
           setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 1));

           //create border and panel title

          setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Amount"));

          //add text fields to the panel.
          add(baked_beans_JT);
          add(Cornflakes_JT);
          add(Sugar_JT);
          add(Tea_Bags_JT);
          add(Instant_Coffee_JT);
          add(Bread_JT);
          add(Sausage_JT);
          add(egg_JT);
          add(milk_JT);
          add(potatoes_JT);


       }



}
```

in the code above i am trying to make the jtextfield accept a number and calculate the number with the checkbox selected, for example: if baked_beans checkbox is selected and the user inputs 2 in the quantity panel (baked_beans_JT), the program should multiply both of them to get the charge...

I did that and in the grocery_items class i get an error in this code:

```
 if (baked_beans_box.isSelected())
         charges += Baked_Beans * qty.getBeanqty();
```

saying "The method getBeanqty() is undefined for the type 
 quantitypanel"

and in the quantity panel class i get an error with this code:

```
public double getBeanqty()
         {

             return Double.parseDouble(baked_beans_JT.getText());
         }
```

the error states:`Syntax error on token "double", @ expected`
please help is needed

thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncomment this declaration as `qty` is used in the `Grocery_items` class:

```
// private quantitypanel qty; // A panel for quantity
```

Also, the method `getBeanqty` is embedded in the constructor `quantitypanel`. You cannot have a method within a method. Move it out of the the scope of the constructor:

```
public double getBeanqty() {
   return Double.parseDouble(baked_beans_JT.getText());
}
```

Java Naming conventions show that class names start with a uppercase letter and underscores are typically not used which would give you `QuantityPanel` and `GroceryItems`.